# Sort a list where predecessor and successor define the sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to sort a list of LineItems where in each LineItem there is a predecessor and successor defined.

```
LineItem{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int? PredecessorId {get;set;}
   public int? SuccessorId {get;set;}
}
```

The first LineItem will have no PredecessorId and the last LineItem  will not have a SuccessorId.

I thought I could just implement IComparable but for 2 only items its not possible calculate the sort in this case.

How would I sort a list `List<LineItem>`?

> Edit

Here is a sample

```
 List<LineItem> lineItems = new List<LineItem>{
    new LineItem{ Id = 1, PredecessorId = 2,        SuccessorId = 103},
    new LineItem{ Id = 2, PredecessorId = null,     SuccessorId = 1},
    new LineItem{ Id = 103, PredecessorId = 1,      SuccessorId = 5},
    new LineItem{ Id = 4, PredecessorId = 5,        SuccessorId = null},
    new LineItem{ Id = 5, PredecessorId = 103,      SuccessorId = 4},


};
```

The expected sort would be:

2,1,103,5,4

Comment: So you've define the first and last elements - what about the ones in between (i.e. where there is both a predecessor and successor)?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example input and output to make it clear what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please, share the [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added a sample

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

input:

```
Id = 2, PredecessorId = 1, SuccessorId = 3
Id = 1, SuccessorId = 2
Id = 3, PredecessorId = 2
```

sort:

```
list.OrderBy(p => p.PredecessorId.HasValue).ThenBy(p => p.PredecessorId.HasValue).OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

output:

```
Id 1, PredecessorId , SuccessorId 2
Id 2, PredecessorId 1, SuccessorId 3
Id 3, PredecessorId 2, SuccessorId
```

Comment: This sorts first and last item correctly but not the items between them. The last OrderBy assumes ids hold the sorting order

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the two items with `null` values in the `where` clause, sort the rest, [Prepend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8) and [Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.8) them to the sorted list:

```cs
var sortedList = lineItems
    .Where(x => x.PredecessorId != null && x.SuccessorId != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Prepend(lineItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PredecessorId == null))
    .Append(lineItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SuccessorId == null))
    .Where(x => x != null).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedList.Select(x => x.Id)));
```

The output is:

```
2, 1, 3, 5, 4
```

If its possible to have a list that contains more than two items with `null` value properties like:

```cs
var lineItems = new List<LineItem>
{
    new LineItem{ Id = 1, PredecessorId = 2, SuccessorId = 3},
    new LineItem{ Id = 2, PredecessorId = null, SuccessorId = 1},
    new LineItem{ Id = 3, PredecessorId = 1, SuccessorId = 5},
    new LineItem{ Id = 4, PredecessorId = 5, SuccessorId = null},
    new LineItem{ Id = 5, PredecessorId = 3, SuccessorId = 4},
    new LineItem{ Id = 6, PredecessorId = null, SuccessorId = 6},
    new LineItem{ Id = 7, PredecessorId = 7, SuccessorId = null},
};
```

Then you could do instead:

```cs
var sortedList = lineItems
    .Where(x => x.PredecessorId != null && x.SuccessorId != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();

sortedList.InsertRange(0, lineItems
    .Where(x => x.PredecessorId == null).OrderBy(x => x.Id));

sortedList.AddRange(lineItems
    .Where(x => x.SuccessorId == null).OrderBy(x => x.Id));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedList.Select(x => x.Id)));
```

Or, create `Prepend` and `Append` extension methods that take `IEnumerable<LineItem>` type:

```cs
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(
        this List<T> source, IEnumerable<T> element)
    {
        source.InsertRange(0, element);
        return source;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(
        this List<T> source, IEnumerable<T> element)
    {
        source.AddRange(element);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Then get the sorted list as follows:

```cs
var sortedList = lineItems
    .Where(x => x.PredecessorId != null && x.SuccessorId != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList()
    .Prepend(lineItems.Where(x => x.PredecessorId is null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)).ToList()
    .Append(lineItems.Where(x => x.SuccessorId is null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedList.Select(x => x.Id)));
```

Both output is:

```
2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7
```

---

> **Edit for an Edit**

---

Using the new extension method `Append` only:

```cs
var sortedList = lineItems
    .Where(x => x.PredecessorId is null &&
    x.SuccessorId != null).ToList()
    .Append(lineItems.Where(x => x.PredecessorId != null &&
    x.SuccessorId != null)).ToList()
    .Append(lineItems.Where(x => x.PredecessorId != null &&
    x.SuccessorId is null)).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedList.Select(x => x.Id)));
```

The result:

```
2, 1, 103, 5, 4
```

Comment: the sample data was implying that sorting by id would work which is not the case